# Navegação de chaves composta

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Ola, tenho um classe com 2 chaves composta

```
 public class Produto_Empresa
 {
        [Key,Column(Order = 0)]
        public int id_produto { get; set; }

        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        public int id_empresa { get; set; }
 }
```

Gostaria de saber se é certo eu coloca isso na Produto_Empresa:

```
public virtual Produto produto { get; set; }


public class Produto
{
       public int id { get; set; }
}
```

Ou colocar `public virtual ICollection<Produto_Empresa> ProdutoEmpresa { get; set; }` na classe Produto.

Comment: Falta um contexto, você fez um relacionamento muitos para muitos pela classe Produto_Empresa, mas,,,,,,,,, a pergunta falta mais dados e uma observação: você tem um chave composta com 2 campos correto ?!

Comment: Sim, a Produto_Empresa  tem 2 chaves primárias, que é da tabela produto e da tabela empresa

Comment: Você exatamente está fazendo o que?

Comment: Quero saber como que fica o relacionamento, dentro das classes, usando 2 chaves composta primárias

Comment: Se usa algum ORM?

Comment: to usando o Entity Framework

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65073/discussion-between-virgilio-novic-and-alysson-bormann).